# IIS Rewrite causing redirect issues

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, iis-8

I have the following rules in IIS.

```
    <rules>
        <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:3000/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
```

My web application internally calls another domain `www.anotherdomain.com/somepage`. My problem is while it redirects, it changes the url to `www.mycurrentdomain.com/somepage` which obviously results in a 404 page. Can some one please help me to write the correct rule.

Note - the redirect is happening from the application code `res.redirect('www.anotherdomain.com/somepage')`

Comment: Notice that you showed a rewrite rule, not a redirect rule, so "it changes the url to www.mycurrentdomain.com/somepage" is not caused by IIS, and you cannot fix that from here. Try to locate the actual cause first.

Comment: @LexLi it works perfect locally. only when i deploy it on iis, i am facing this issue.

Comment: @LexLi, also notice I am using reverse proxy. So the redirect code is written inside my application. I was thinking of a way to block `anotherdomain` requests.

Comment: You have to dig further into the web framework you use (Node.js I assume), as without an outbound rule IIS won't change the redirection response (`res.redirect('www.anotherdomain.com/somepage'`) to `www.mycurrentdomain.com/somepage`. Maybe that framework decides wrongly for you.

Answer (score 2):

We need to handle outbound rules to apply the URL rewrite rule rather than use inbound rules. Here is an example of stopping the internally call redirecting to outside domain(`https://www.bing.com`). You can change it according to your actual needs.

```
  <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <outboundRules>
                <rule name="MyLocationRule" preCondition="IsRedirection">
                    <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Location" pattern="https://www.bing.com/" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="http://{HTTP_HOST}/webform2.aspx" />
                </rule>
                <preConditions>
                    <preCondition name="IsRedirection">
<!--301,302 Url redirection http status code.-->
                        <add input="{RESPONSE_STATUS}" pattern="3\d\d" />
                    </preCondition>
                </preConditions>
            </outboundRules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
```

Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.

Comment: i am going to try this next week.